# how to add time datatype in sqldf?

Tags: r, datetime-format, sqldf

below is a reproducible example, I would like to add time+duration and return an object as time format, for example 9:00 + 35 I need to output 9:35 and so on. so what is the best way to do it in sqldf. I know how to do it using r but need in sqldf code? anyhelp would be much appreciated.

```r
df <- data.frame(
            author = c('Tom','Jerry', 'Nick'),
            time = c('9:00','9:50','10:30'),
            duration_min = c(35,30,20)
)
```

Comment: What have you tried? How would you do this without sqldf and what are you using up to this point with sqldf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `df` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end, assuming you want to use the default SQLite backend to `sqldf` then use `substr` to ensure that the hours are in the form HH and not just H and then use the [SQLite time function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
sqldf("select 
    *, 
    time(substr('0' || time, -5), duration_min || ' minutes') as time2 
  from df")
```

giving:

```
  author  time duration_min    time2
1    Tom  9:00           35 09:35:00
2  Jerry  9:50           30 10:20:00
3   Nick 10:30           20 10:50:00
```

### Note

Note that we must use equal signs rather than <- in defining the columns of `df` as `author` etc. are *arguments* to `data.frame`.

```
df <- data.frame(
            author = c('Tom','Jerry', 'Nick'),
            time = c('9:00','9:50','10:30'),
            duration_min = c(35,30,20))
```